# How do I get the string mapping from tensorflow datasets dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Apologies if this has an obvious answer, I feel like it should.
When using Tensorflow Datasets the labels are automatically integers but you can display them via the API to get the string mapping.
For example in CIFAR10 7 corresponds to horse.
How can I get these mappings?
Do I have to download the dataset and get them from the folder/dir names?
Or is there another way?

Cheers

Edit: as Amel pointed out below, the reason why I think it must be accessible somehow is because when calling show examples, the class names show up next to the integer labels.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use train_ds.class_names (train_ds is the dataset)

for example:

```
class_names = train_ds.class_names
for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
    print(labels)
    for i in range(0, 5):
        print(labels[i])
        print(class_names[labels[i]])
```

Here, you can see that labels[i] is a tensor with an integer and class_names[labels[i]] is the string corresponding.

Comment: thank you. Does this work with all tensorflow datasets in the catalog?
I get AttributeError: '_OptionsDataset' object has no attribute 'class_names' running this

Comment: I don't think so. It works for the customized datasets created as tf.data.dataset but not for the tfds in the catalog. However, the information should be available somewhere because when you use show_examples function you got the labels. Maybe you should ask for this argument to be available in ds_info on tensorflow-datasets [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+-label%3A%22dataset+request%22+)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly why I know it's somewhere. It works with show examples, but I get the error with your code and there is nothing in the info dict either.
However class names are availables as folders in when downloaded.